# Changing the ArcGIS Server 10.3 context root

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3

I have a arcgis 10.3 server running on a machine (dev)
and i want to something like following

http://server1/devarcgis/rest....... (dev)

I have changed the the context root of arcgis apps (dev) in

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml
```

file from arcgis to devarcgis but its not working and its context root is still arcgis instead of devarcgis. Any idea what might be wrong here?

EDIT:

I edited C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\contexts\rootapp\WEB-INF\urlrewriter.xml file and added a rule

```
<rule enabled="true">
    <from>^/devarcgis/rest(/*)(.*)$</from>
    <to context="arcgis/rest" last="true">/$2</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>^/devarcgis/rest/services(/*)(.*)$</from>
    <to context="arcgis/rest/services" last="true">/$2</to>
</rule>
```

now  a call to

```
http://localhost/devarcgis/rest/services/myservice/MapServer/export?f=json......
```

returns

```
ags_jsonp.ags_jsonp_7_48333({"href":"http://localhost/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/myservice/_ags_map784f1c72c2a24befa3e0519617d2ef80.png................
```

in response.

Comment: Since you have a web server running on port 80, it should be trivial to configure a proxy to rewrite `/devarcgis/` to  `http://127.0.0.1:6080/arcgis/`.  I don't think it would be wise to make changes to the Tomcat configuration embedded within ArcGIS Server.

Comment: @Vince see the updated question

Comment: That is pretty much opposite of what I was recommending.  You should not change the internals of ArcGIS Server.  What you *can* safely control is the way the Web Adapter is configured and how your web server is configured.

Comment: @Vince but if i configured to rewrite url from devarcgis to arcgis samee thing will happen i.e. export will return ags_jsonp.ags_jsonp_7_48333({"href":"http://localhost/arcgis

Comment: Leave ArcGIS alone on it's default port, and manage proxy rewrites through the web server.  This isn't really even a GIS issue, just a webserver configuration task.

Comment: @Vince i used apache 2.2 (reverted arcgis to its default) to rewrite the url, redirect is working but again last problem  i.e. export will return ags_jsonp.ags_jsonp_7_48333({"href":"localhost/arcgis.........

Comment: Please edit the question focus on this different issue. If it remains a 'mod_proxy' configuration problem, the question will likely be closed as off-topic.